# How to pass an array of variables from a laravel controller to my ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have an ajax function:

```
  $.get('/updateAssignment', {title: title, id: id, class: subject, date: date, description: description}, function(data)
  {

    window.location.hash = data;

  });
```

And it works fine, this is my function in my controller that is routed to the above ajax call:

```
public function updateAssignment()
{

  // Bunch of code here

  return 'hello world';

}
```

Now I know that whatever I return, will be in the jQuery variable `data`, but I want more than one "value".

How would I return something like

```
return array('title' => $title, 'description' => $description, etc...)
```

to my `data` variable in jQuery and be able to use it like:

`$('h2').val(data['title']);` Or anything similar

Thank you in advance, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try to return a JSON string from your controller and access individual components with `data.title` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel 5, use `response()` to return a JSON object from an AJAX call, like this:

```
return response(['title' => $title, 'description' => $description]);
```

In your Javascript, you would then access this data using object notation, so:

```
$.get("URL", function(data){
    var title = data.title;
    var description = data.description;
    // Etc, etc
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class AssignmentViewModels
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string class { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }


    public JsonResult updateAssignment(string title, string id, string class, string date, string description)
    {
        var model = new AssignmentViewModels();// if you have a list of data return, make "List<AssignmentViewModels>()" ,& in Ajax sucess method, make a foreach loop & collect the data.
        model = repository._update(title,id,class,date,description);//return updated data
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    var URL = ResolvedUrl.replace('ActionName', 'updateAssignment').replace('ControllerName', 'YourController');
    var data = { title: title, id: id, class: subject, date: date, description: description };
    $.get(URL, data, function (result) {
            if ($('#h2')[0]) {
                $('#h2').val(result.title);// no need to use JSON.parse
            }
    }
```